# SQL query to Match a word from the database with given letters

Tags: jquery, sql

for example i have these letters "A,X,E,R,T,Q,S,E,W,N,G,N,E,R,I,B,S,O,N,S,I,U,I,E,R,T,S,G,F,S,B,S,A,H"

and I have this table

`fname     |    mname      | lname

NERISON    |  SAYSON       | PITOGO
NERISON1   |  SAYSON1      | PITOGO1
NERISON2   |  SAYSON2      | PITOGO2
NERISON3   |  SAYSON3      | PITOGO3
NERISON4   |  SAYSON4      | PITOGO4
NERISON5   |  SAYSON5      | PITOGO5`

It can be seen that "NERISON" can be found in the given letters. How can I do that to an SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

You can't because you have to do some sort of iteration through the database field value, i.e in your case a `varchar` variable of some sort. SQL is not designed for these kind of operations. You may want to look into the concept of relational databases to see what is the purpose of SQL.